# What reasons could justify Apple's HTML5 demos use of HTML4 doctypes?

Tags: html, doctype

Some of [Apple's HTML 5 demos use an html4 loose doctype](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/HTML_video_example/Listings/last_time_i_saw_paris_html.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

What reasons could they have for not using the HTML5 doctype?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

EDIT: I am really looking for technical answers here not political, perhaps I should of reworded this question to "What could be gained from using an HTML4 doctype when using HTML5?" - Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Maybe they wanted to indicate that these features weren't dependent on HTML5, that they worked anyway.

Comment: I don't see any HTML 5 element or tag in the second example.

Comment: right you are, removed second example, ta

Comment: because HTML5 is just a marketing term to them.

Comment: They are using a WYSIWYG editor which automatically inserts a HTML4 DOCTYPE. On a side note I've noticed it is a lot nicer to give answers as comments instead of as actual answers, so +1s to you all.

Comment: Why is everyone using comments for their answers?

Comment: @BalusC - I'd love to though as I'm not an Apple certified developer - I can't seem to access the forums - http://developer.apple.com/devforums/

Comment: “t is a lot nicer to give answers as comments instead of as actual answers” — you think? Comments can‘t be edited later, so they can get out of date, and they can’t be voted up or accepted, so it’s harder to sift the good answers from the bad.

Answer (score 7):

Because those demos are just marketing. They are not built using best practice and they do not really show much HTML5 at all.

In fact, they even block Google Chrome 5 and suggest that you'd upgrade to Safari 4. LOL!

Comment: That last paragraph... How Apple-like.

Answer (score 5):

Because behind that Fortune 500 company, the marketing veneer and all that imposing technical knowledge/reputation is just a group of people who sometimes make mistakes. Same as you and me.

Consider it a bug and report it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they use some tags that have been dropped in HTML5, and don’t use any of the new tags in HTML5? So they leave in an HTML 4 doctype to make the pages easier to validate?

I can’t think of a good reason.